# ERROR: Column 'col_name' not found with createSQLQuery

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

```
String sql = "select field1, field2, field3 from sample where field3=:field3 order by field_id asc";
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql).addEntity(Sample.class);
    query.setParameter("field3", 1);
    return query.list();
```

In sample table I have one more column named field4. But I dont want fetch it here.

With this sql, I get Error as below.

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Column 'field4' not found.
```

Comment: but you are trying to morph the output of the SQL into the `Sample` class

Comment: Are you sure you created this column? if you added this column later and did not change your database version, try to do a "clear data" for your app in your emulator or device

Comment: Yes. Otherwise it is difficult to convert it to Sample class objects

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql = "select field1 as field1Sample, field2 as field2Sample, field3 as field3Sample from sample where field3=:field3 order by field_id asc";
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
    query.setParameter("field3", 1);
    query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Sample.class))
    return query.list();
```

This worked.
Used field alias for Sample class like.

field1 as field1Sample: field1Sample is the property name in in Sample class